# What is the origin of decade-unit inversion?

Tags: indo-european, numbers

Some Indo-European languages (e.g. English, Spanish, French, most Slavic languages) have a big-endian pronunciation of numbers: 153 is hundred-and-fifty-and-three. Others (e.g. German, Sanskrit, ancient Greek) invert the order of tens and ones: 153 is hundred-and-three-and-fifty. (The "and"s may be present or implicit, depending on the language.)

Why? Was there ever a point where the inversion was present (or not) in all Indo-European languages?

(I suspect that it might be a change that just happens randomly, as there seem to be differences in non-Indo-European languages too -- [Arabic](https://omniglot.com/language/numbers/arabic.htm) has the inversion, [Mandarin](https://omniglot.com/language/numbers/chinese.htm) doesn't. But the scope of the question is only Indo-European languages, as I don't want to make it too broad.)

Comment: I noticed that the inversion is also present in old(er) English novels. So English seems to have had the inversion, but they gave it up during the last 100...200 years.

Comment: Fifteen looks a bit inverted as well